# How can I fix to avoid a memory leak?

Tags: c++

I have created the push_back function to add a number at the end of the array.
But I think there is some causes to leak in this code below.
Could you find the causes?

```
void ElasticArray::push_back(int item){
    
    if(_max_size == _size){
        int* tmpArray = nullptr;
        tmpArray = new int[_size * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++){
            tmpArray[i] = _array[i];
        }
        _array = tmpArray;
        _max_size = _size * 2;
        delete[] tmpArray;
        tmpArray = nullptr;
    }

    else if(_max_size == 0){
        _max_size = 16;
    }

    if(_max_size > _size){
        _array[_size] = item;
        _size++;
    }
    
    _array[_size] = item;
    _size++;
}
```

Comment: `delete[] tmpArray;` After this, the previously assigned `_array = tmpArray;` is left pointing to invalid memory, and the next access `_array[_size]` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You probably should be putting `delete[] _array` prior to assigning `_array=tmp_array` and remove the one below.

Comment: Why do you "think there is some causes to leak in this code"?

Comment: The function contains several bugs. The case `_max_size == _size` results in a memory leak 100% of the time (assuming `_array` is not `nullptr`) since you delete the new array, not the old one. Furthermore the case where `_max_size` starts off as 0 (which is probably already covered by the previous condition and may never actually result in the body of the if bein executed) does not allocate an array of size 16 which seems to be the state you actually want to end up in.

Comment: Moreover if `_max_size > _size` is true you assign item to an element in the array and then assign it again to an positon that may be outside of the range of valid indices.

Comment: Did you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) after compiling your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole function is coded all wrong. It has multiple problems due to mismanagement of your variables, thus causing a *memory leak*, a *buffer overflow*, AND *undefined behavior*.

If `_max_size` is 0, then presumably `_size` is also 0 (otherwise you have more bugs elsewhere in your code), and you end up allocating 0 elements. `_max_size` never gets a chance to be set to 16. But if, for some reason, `_max_size` was 0 but `_size` was not, then `_max_size` would get set to 16 but nothing would actually get allocating for `_array` to point at, causing undefined behavior on subsequent accesses to the contents of `_array`..

Even if you did allocate something, you are assigning `_tmpArray` to `_array` before calling `delete[]` on `_array`, causing a leak. And then you call `delete[]` on the memory you just assigned to `_array`, causing more undefined behavior on subsequent accesses to the contents of `_array`.

Worse, even if you were growing the array properly, you are pushing each `item` into the array *twice*, because `if(_max_size > _size)` will always be true by that point in the code (if you are doing everything else correctly), which will eventually cause a buffer overflow, corrupting memory.

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
void ElasticArray::push_back(int item){
    
    if ((_max_size == _size) || (_max_size == 0)){
        int new_max = (_max_size != 0) ? (_max_size * 2) : 16;
        int* tmpArray = new int[new_max];
        for(int i = 0; i < _size; ++i){
            tmpArray[i] = _array[i];
        }
        delete[] _array;
        _array = tmpArray;
        _max_size = new_max;
    }
    
    _array[_size] = item;
    _size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning  _array = tmpArray and after that your calling delete on tmpArrary then again you are accessing the _array

```
        _array = tmpArray;
        _max_size = _size * 2;
        delete[] tmpArray;
        tmpArray = nullptr;
```

_array stores the start address of  the memory location pointed by tempArray

e.g : if the start memory Location of tempArray is 0x00f39f38
then after

```
_array = tmpArray;
```

_array will also point to 0x00f39f38

so when you call

```
delete tmpArray
tmpArray = nullptr;
```

tempArray starts pointing to null 0x00000000 but the address which is pointed by _array
is still 0x00f39f38 so when you do

```
_array[_size] = item;
    _size++;
```

you will get a undefined behavior depending on the OS and compiler

> Suggestion

Use  std::vectors or perform a deep Copy
while doing _array=tempArray